# Javascript select in table cell

Tags: javascript, select, html-table

I want to add a select (dropdown) to every row in my table.
The table is created using Javascript and has dynamic content imported from xml files using JQuery.
I managed to import all content successfully, however the dropdowns are displayed in the last row only.
I would appreciate if you can assist me to have the dropdown in every row.

Below is a code extract with blank selects only (the imported content is stored in those elements). All outputs such as "row " is for testing purpose only. "Numrows" are for testing purpose as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" >

    <title>table select test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="scrolltable">
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabbody = document.getElementById("scrolltable");

    var types = document.createElement("select");
    var units = document.createElement("select");

    parseTable(3, types, "row ", units);

    function parseTable(numrows, types, limits, units) {
        for (i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
            cell1.style.width="300px";
            cell1.appendChild(types);
            row.appendChild(cell1);
            var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
            cell2.innerHTML = limits + i;
            cell2.style.width = "100px";
            row.appendChild(cell2);
            var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
            cell3.appendChild(units);
            row.appendChild(cell3);
            tabbody.appendChild(row);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a minimum example, it may be difficult to pinpoint the issue, but my guess is:

You create the types and units elements only before your loop, so you are appending the same objects over and over, and each time you append one of them to a cell, you take it from the original cell and put it into the new one. Thats what "appendChild" does, it doesn't clone the element, it uses the same one (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

If you create a new select element in every step of your for, you should be fine =)

Comment: Thank you very much. Moving the declaration into the loop indeed solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`types` and `units` are defined once, so they are single elements. So they are moved to where you last called appendChild. If you want to see what happens, try adding `alert('');` before ending your for loop and see it in action for every row.

If you want to add it in every row then you need new instances at each itterration:

```
function parseTable(numrows, types, limits, units) {
    for (i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        cell1.style.width="300px";
        types = document.createElement("select");
        cell1.appendChild(types);
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        cell2.innerHTML = limits + i;
        cell2.style.width = "100px";
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
        units = document.createElement("select");
        cell3.appendChild(units);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        tabbody.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```